# Citation request for Ganesha's dhyana sloka

Tags: ganesha, shloka, reference-request, iconography, dhyana

Recently I came across these statues of *Gaṇeśa* currently held in museums overseas.

[Statue 1](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dancing_Ganesh,_North_Bengal,_11th_century_AD,_schist_-_Ethnological_Museum,_Berlin_-_DSC01608.JPG)
[Statue 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ganesh_%28mus%C3%A9e_d%27art_asiatique_de_Berlin%29.jpg)
[Statue 3](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dancing_Ganesha_-_Basalt_-_Circa_12th_Century_CE_-_North_Bengal_-_ACCN_9205_-_Indian_Museum_-_Kolkata_2014-02-14_9292.JPG)

All of these statues were found in the northern parts of undivided Bengal, date around the 11th - 12th century AD & are carved in the art that was prevalent in the [Pāla Empire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pala_Empire). All 3 portray an 8-armed *Gaṇapati* dancing on his mount, the mouse, under a mango tree. Out of his *āyudha*s, only 4 - the axe, the rosary, the vessel filled with *modaka*s & the sugarcane were distinctly identifiable. Descriptors for this form label it as *Nṛtya-gaṇapati* however the *dhyāna-sloka* for *Nṛtya-gaṇapati* as recorded in the *Śrītattvanidhi* of *Kṛṣṇarāja* III of Mysore records Him to be of 4-armed. I was unable to find the mention of this form elsewhere.

So can anybody cite the *dhyāna-sloka* for this particular form of *Gaṇeśa*?